# Group by in django create wrong query

Tags: python, mysql, django

we have write down this query in django

```
ManageInterview.objects.filter
(post_id=request.data['job_id'])
.order_by('-id')
.annotate(total=Count('pitcher_id'))
```

After print this we got this query

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`pitcher_invitations`.`pitcher_id`) AS `total` FROM 
`pitcher_invitations` WHERE `pitcher_invitations`.`post_id` = 254555444
GROUP BY `pitcher_invitations`.`id` 
ORDER BY `pitcher_invitations`.`id` DESC
```

We are doing group by

> pitcher_id

but django query group by

> `pitcher_invitations`.`id`

we want this query

```
select * from `pitcher_invitations` where `post_id` =254555444
group by `pitcher_id` order by `id` desc
```

Comment: Django is not creating a wrong query. Your query set is not what you need. Why do you want to select all columns while you are grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
query ="select * from `pitcher_invitations` where `post_id` = "+str(request.data['job_id'])+" group by `pitcher_id` order by `id` desc"

result = ManageInterview.objects.raw(query)
```

If anyone has good solution please share

Answer (score 1):

You can't select * and group_by. If you wanna group `pitcher_id` and count records you don't need to provide the *, it can be done with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

query = ManageInterview.objects.filter(post_id=request.data['job_id'])
query = query.values('pitcher_id').annotate(total=Count('pitcher_id'))
```